# Electron app error undefined symbol: udata_setCommonData_59?

Tags: node.js, electron

Getting this error when I try to run an AppImage package for Scatter (EOS wallet). This seems to be a recurrent error for AppImage packages.
Don't know much about Electron based apps to debug the error.

Comment: You'll need to post the code you're running that gives you that error

Comment: well is not code, is an app (AppImage) I am trying to run on Arch Linux. so chmod +x foo.appimage and ./foo.appimage 

``tmp/.mount_linux-6hUzPY/scatter: symbol lookup error: /tmp/.mount_linux-6hUzPY/scatter: undefined symbol: udata_setCommonData_59``